# The ability to check the value entered in the custom property using try-catch

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, properties, user-controls

I've been created the user control based on Button and the custom property inside. Now I'm trying to create the ability to check the value entered in the custom property using try-catch on set in design mode of Visual Studio, but when I enter not Int32 value, it displays [standart message box](http://imageshack.com/a/img856/7797/ubh4.png), not mine... How to solve this problem?

The code:

```
    private int timeDisplayTip;
    [CategoryAttribute("My properties")]
    public int TimeDisplayTip
    {
        get
        {
            return timeDisplayTip;
        }
        set
        {               
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString() != value.ToString())
                    throw new FormatException();

                timeDisplayTip = value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private int timeDisplayTip;
[CategoryAttribute("My properties")]
public string TimeDisplayTip
{
    get
    {
        return timeDisplayTip.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString() != value.ToString())
                throw new FormatException();

            timeDisplayTip = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps...